# CodeIngiter base url not working on live server

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have a php codeignitor php app which was working fine on localserver xampp but when i uploaded that app on a live server, its not loading assets, images and also not submitting the login form. When see the source for login page, it shows urls like this

```
<link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

also the form action shows like that

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>auth/login" method="post">
```

i have tried every thing url helpers and all that stuff but still unable to fix it.

Comment: In `application/config.config.php` what is assigned to `$config['base_url']`? It must be set and set correctly or all kinds of bad and unpredictable things happen. Also, you can pass the URI string to `base_url()` like this -  `<link href="<?=base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: in localhost i have set it to empty but on live server i am setting url but still not working. Tried all possible urls.

Comment: show ur code $config['base_url''] = '';

Comment: Make sure you set your base_url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Comment: Do you have short-code enabled on live server?  CodeIgniter docs recommend not using PHP short codes for this reason.  Should be `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: yes my config.php has the same value set $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/'; but its not affecting any thing to links whether i put something in it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if is too obvious, but I assume that you have the url helper loaded in your autoload, right?

Comment: i do loaded url helper. in the autoload.php. but nothing is happening. my server is a lamp stack on amazon ec2

Comment: here is the link to site. please check the source. http://54.206.29.44/old/

Comment: Okay, i checked it out. The problem is that the browser is not "reading" your php code. Are you sure your file extension is .php? I could bet that may be .html

UPDATE: You said it was working locally, so what I said is not the problem. Sounds like if your production server doesn't have php installed. Kinda weird though. Do you have access to the php config in your server? Are you sure is running? Do other bits of php code run in your server?

If all of that is a yes, then I'm keen to say I know what your error is: I don't have a clue.

Comment: yes the server is running up. also other php is working fine. config.php file extension is in php. Everything is perfect but didnt understand why is this happening. i have changed the domain name to pos.mypos.ws and it still not working